# How can I grab variable from URL using JavaScript and display it on screen?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using the following script:

```
        function getQueryVariable(variable)
{
       var query = window.location.search.substring(1);
       var vars = query.split("&");
       for (var i=0;i<vars.length;i++) {
               var pair = vars[i].split("=");
               if(pair[0] == variable){return pair[1];}
       }
              var id_is = getQueryVariable("id");

document.write(id_is);

       return(false);

}
```

This script should grab the variable value and display it on screen.  It only works if I use getQueryVariable("id"); in the console but using the document.write method it doesn't work.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What you're doing wrong is using `document.write()` probably. You'll have to post more about what you're doing and what your page looks like to get more specific help.

Answer (score 2):

You should call document.write when the page is loaded .

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function getQueryVariable(variable)
{
   var query = window.location.search.substring(1);
   var vars = query.split("&");
   for (var i=0;i<vars.length;i++) {
           var pair = vars[i].split("=");
           if(pair[0] == variable){
            return pair[1];
          }
   }
}


var id_is = getQueryVariable("id");

window.onload = function(){
  document.write(id_is);
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a function that gets the query parameter from a URL, such as this:

```
function getURLParameter(name) {
    return decodeURIComponent((new RegExp('[?|&]' + name + '=' + '([^&;]+?)(&|#|;|$)').exec(location.search)||[,""])[1].replace(/\+/g, '%20'))||null
}
```

If the query is `hello` and it equals `world`, i.e. `http://www.website.com/index.html?hello=world`.
Then you can use `getURLParameter('hello')` to return it.

Answer (score 0):

```
var url =window.location.search;

function getQueryParam(name,url) {
    return decodeURIComponent((new RegExp('[?|&]' + name + '=' + '([^&;]+?)(&|#|;|$)').exec(url)||[,""])[1].replace(/\+/g, '%20'))||null
}

var result=getQueryParam(id,url);
document.write(result);
```